# how to export every output in a loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation

```
library(SMFI5)

for(i in 1:10)

{
 simulateloop<-sim.vasicek(0.001987455,0.001614103,0.000186756,-0.001,30,1)
 print(simulateloop)
}

simulateloop
```

The `sim.vasicek()` function will creat both data output and a graph output, I only want to export every data output by row or by column, so i can use `colMeans()` or `rowMeans()` to calculate the average value of these 10 simulations, but I can only get one data output rather than 10 different data output. Could anyone tell me how to export all the 10 different data output by row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replicate` which will return you 10 columns on which you can use `colMeans`

```
library(SMFI5)
simulateloop <- replicate(10, sim.vasicek(0.001987455,0.001614103,0.000186756,-0.001,30,1))
```

---

To use `for` loop you can store the result in a list

```
simulateloop <- vector('list', length = 10)

for(i in 1:10){
  simulateloop[[i]]<- sim.vasicek(0.001987455,0.001614103,0.000186756,-0.001,30,1)
}
```

and then use `sapply` to take `mean`

```
sapply(simulateloop, mean)
```

Comment: Wow, Ronak,thank you very much! It really works, could you also tell me how to use for-loop to make it? Because I also want to learn it.

Comment: @XUNZHANG Updated the answer using `for` loop.

Comment: no,Ronak, like in your first answer, I will use rowMeans() to get 31 average value instead of 10 average value, so your second answer should make some change?

Comment: @XUNZHANG If you want 31 values, you can convert it to dataframe and then use `rowMeans` like `rowMeans(data.frame(simulateloop))`

Comment: Hi, Ronak, sorry to disturb you again, if I want to do it 5000 or 10000 times,do you know how to reduce the running time of the code? It takes me half an hour to do it 5000 times.

Comment: I am not sure exactly, how you can do that in the current code. Maybe you can ask a new question to have better ideas on how to implement this.

Comment: replicate(5000, sim.vasicek(0.001987455,0.001614103,0.000186756,-0.001,30,1))  sorry, I don't ask my question clearly, this is what I mean